# Give Matematica Solve function only references to equations instead of whole equations?

Tags: syntax, wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language

How do I supply the Matematica Solve function with only references to equations, instead of whole equations?

I.e. let's say I have multiple equations, like:

```
eq1 = {x + y == 0}
eq2 = {x y - 2 == 0}
```

However, when I try to put them in Solve, Matematica throws an error:

```
Solve[{eq1 && eq2}, {x, y}]
Solve::naqs: {x+y==0}&&{-2+x y==0} is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities.
```

At the same time, re-writing whole equations works

```
Solve[x + y == 0 && x y - 1 == 0, {x, y}]
{{x->-I,y->I},{x->I,y->-I}}
```

but can quickly become cumbersome when the number and complexity of equations increases.

Comment: Try `eq1 = x+y==0; eq2 = x y-2==0; Solve[{eq1,eq2},{x,y}]` or `eq1 = x+y==0;
eq2 = x y-2==0; Solve[eq1&&eq2,{x,y}]`

Comment: It seems you may not be aware of the purpose of curly braces. They denote lists. Don't put the equations in lists here. If you do, it is not possible to join them with `&&`.

Comment: Thank you @Bill for the solution. Both approaches appear to work correctly.

Comment: @Szabolcs Indeed, I did not know. I must admit that some syntactic concepts obvious for experienced users are quite obscure for those who begin without human guidance. Thank you very much for the clarification!